# I have following node.js code which get repeated in multiple .js files -

Tags: node.js

```
const c1 = require('package1')
const c2 = require('package2')
const c3 = require('package3')
const c4 = require('package4')
const c5 = require('package5')
const c6 = require('package6')
const iodata;

function foo()
{
  let secretpath = "../abc/def/file.txt"
  let filedata = await readCredentialsFromFile(secretPath); 
  iodata = filedata[0]; // iodata initialized to be used in other files.
  return filedata;
}
```

How to refactor it in a way that I have to write only one ***require*** statement in each file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like so?

commonDeps.js

```
exports.c1 = require("package1")
exports.c2 = require("package2")
exports.c3 = require("package3")
```

a.js

```
const cc = require("./commonDeps");
const c1 = cc.c1;
```

b.js

```
const c2 = require("./commonDeps").c2;
```

c.js

```
import {c3} from "./commonDeps"
```